# Does the term "dwelling" indicate living "inside"

Tags: meaning

I am writing study about habitat preferences of bats. **It examines tree-dwelling (inside cavities) and foliage roosting bats.**

My problem is to find the right term which is able to ***incorporate both groups***. I was thinking that **tree-dwelling bats is maybe the right word.**
But I have doubts if "dwelling" does not indicate that animals use space "inside" of the tree.

**Are tree-dwelling bats defined as all bats which use trees ("inside" in cavities and "outside" by hanging on branches), or it is reserved only for "inside" living animals?**

Comment: I think a dwelling is just a housing. Inside, outside, over, under. Doesn't matter I don't think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, I agree with the selection of Tree-dwelling for bats that live either within a cavity or foliage of a tree. Though in situations such as this, I would advise looking at the scholarly papers within your field of study, rather than in a general English sense. Words can be used in much different context and meaning inside science groups than used in mainstream English use. Based on a quick [jstor search](http://www.jstor.org/action/doAdvancedSearch?f3=all&c5=AND&c2=AND&f0=all&acc=off&ed=&q4=&q2=&c3=AND&f2=all&sd=&c4=AND&c6=AND&q0=Tree-dwelling+bats&q6=&q3=&f1=all&c1=AND&f4=all&wc=on&f6=all&pt=&q5=&q1=&la=&f5=all&isbn=), it looks like Tree-dwelling is generally the term applied to bats that make their home inside trees (cavities, foliage). As a specific example of usage see this article from the Journal of Mammalogy [Summer Roost Selection by Tree-Dwelling Bats Nyctalus noctula and N. leisleri: A Multiscale Analysis](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/25145178?sid=21104930267981&uid=3739568&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256)

Comment: Also note that in layperson's English, the inside of the tree is the volume defined by the trunk above ground level _and_ the foliage.  So my cat can get stuck "in a tree" or I can build a fort "in a tree," or a bird can build a nest "in a tree," and in all cases, I could mean "among the branches of a tree."

Comment: Thank you very much @Adam. This definition is very useful to me.

Comment: @LadislavNado Judicious use of the word _"arboreal"_ also wouldn't be out of place in your study.